# AB +A +B=0 for matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $n \geq 3$ and consider the set $R=\lbrace (a_{ij}) \in M_n(\mathbb{R}) \mid a_{ij}=0, \hspace{0.1cm}\text{if}\hspace{0.1cm} i \geq j \rbrace$ of real strictly upper triangle matrices. Now take $A \in R$, can one find an explicit description of a matrix $B \in R$ such that $AB+A+B=0$?

Comment: Note that $(A+I)(B+I)=I$. So find the inverse of $A+I$, subtract $I$ from it to get $B$.

Comment: The identity matrix $I$ is not an element of $R$...

Comment: It doesn't matter...

Comment: You're right, my bad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$B(A+I)=-A$, so $B= -A(A+I)^{-1}$. Since $A+I$ is upper triangular, it's determinant is the product of the diagonal (all 1's). So $(A+I)$ is invertible.

Next, the inverse $C:=(A+I)^{-1}$ must also be upper triangular (prove this) and the product of upper triangular matrices is again upper triangular. Moreover, $[AC]_{ii}=\sum_{k}A_{ii}C_{ii}=0$, so it looks like $B$ will be an element of $R$.

Answer (score 0):

**Note** For each $A \in R$ the matrix $A+I$ has determinant 1 and hence is invertible.

Then 
$$AB+A+B=0 \Leftrightarrow (A+I)(B+I) = I \Leftrightarrow B+I= (A+I)^{-1} \Leftrightarrow \\
B= -I+(A+I)^{-1}$$

You can use the formula 
$$(A+I)^{-1}=\frac{1}{\det(A+I)} \mbox{Adj}(A)=\mbox{Adj}(A+I)$$to see that $-I+(A+I)^{-1}$ is indeed strictly upper triangular.

**Alternate (better) solution**

Note that all eigenvalues of $-A$ are equal to $0$ and hence $-A$ is Nilpotent, meaning $(-A)^n=0$. [This can be seen directly, by observing that $A^2$ has the first diagonal above the main diagonal 0, $A^2$  has the first two diagonals above the main diagonal 0, and so on].

This means that $(-A)^n=0$ and hence 
$$I= I- (-A)^n=(I+A)(I-A+A^2-A^3+...+(-1)^{n-1}A^{n-1})$$

Therefore
$$(I+A)^{-1}= I-A+A^2-A^3+...+(-1)^{n-1}A^{n-1} \\
B=-I-(I-A)^{-1}= A-A^2+A^3+...+(-1)^{n}A^{n-1}$$